# Add corner radius to view borders Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, border, cornerradius

I have a `UIView extension` with a function that adds `borders` to specific edges (which I need). On that function, I am also trying to add `cornerRadius` if the borders are near each other.

Here is my function:

```
func addBorders(withEdges edges: [UIRectEdge],
                    withColor color: UIColor,
                    withThickness thickness: CGFloat) {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomRight, .bottomLeft[![\]][1]][1], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).cgPath

        layer.mask = maskLayer
        
        let border = CAShapeLayer()
        
        edges.forEach({ edge in
            
            border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
            border.name = String(edge.rawValue)
            
            switch edge {
            case .left:
                border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: thickness, height: frame.size.height)
                
                break
                
            case .right:
                border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.size.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height: frame.size.height)
                
                break
                
            case .top:
                border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: thickness)
                
                break
                
            case .bottom:
                border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.size.height - thickness, width: frame.size.width, height: thickness)
                
                break
                
            default:
                break
            }
            
            layer.addSublayer(border)
        })
        
        border.path = maskLayer.path
    }
```

This functions adds the borders well, as I need them, and let's say I need all the borders and corners (based on the hardcoded `byRoundingCorners` value), but the result is at if follows:

[image: Output]

The `cornerRadius` is there, but the borders now are somehow the whole `UIView` not the `thickness` I've sent.

Can somebody help me?

Thank you for your time!

**

### UPDATE

**

So I have updated my function to this:

```
 func addBorders(withEdges edges: [UIRectEdge],
                withColor color: UIColor,
                withThickness thickness: CGFloat) {
    edges.forEach({ edge in
        let border = CALayer()
        border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        border.name = String(edge.rawValue)
        
        switch edge {
        case .left:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: thickness, height: frame.size.height)
            border.cornerRadius = 10
            border.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
            border.masksToBounds = true
            
            break
            
        case .right:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.size.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height: frame.size.height)
            border.cornerRadius = 10
            border.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
            border.masksToBounds = true
            
            break
            
        case .top:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: thickness)
            border.cornerRadius = 10
            border.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
            border.masksToBounds = true
            
            break
            
        case .bottom:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.size.height - thickness, width: frame.size.width, height: thickness)
            border.cornerRadius = 10
            border.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
            border.masksToBounds = true
            
            break
            
        default:
            break
        }
        
        layer.addSublayer(border)
    })
```

and now the output is like that:

[image]

How can I achieve some normal corners?

Comment: Why don’t you just override the draw function and use UIBezzierPath with rounded rect?

Comment: @Ahmed Abaza I don’t really get it how to do that

Comment: Search youtube for cs193p 2017... I think you'll find it very resourceful.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the red lines that you’re drawing (closely, zoom on it with an app like “Zoom It”, you will see that the edges of that red border have been curved out, which i think that is not what you want).

here is what i came up with:

```
  func addBorders(withEdges edges: [UIRectEdge],
                  withColor color: UIColor,
                  withThickness thickness: CGFloat,
                  cornerRadius: CGFloat) {
    layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
    layer.borderWidth = thickness
    layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    edges.forEach({ edge in
      
      switch edge {
        case .left:
          layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
          
        case .right:
          layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
          
        case .top:
          layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
          
        case .bottom:
          layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
          
        default:
          break
      }
    })
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I added `layer.mask = border` but it's the same result

Comment: @poPaTheGuru, check it out now. sorry for the almost misleading :|

Comment: yes, this works if you always want all the borders, but my case is that sometimes i need just two borders, maybe just one or none and if the borders are next to each other i need the corner radius. At the moment i made it possible with some kind of hack, but i am still looking for a much more normal solution